# The hidden part of the menu won't show up when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

Please, help me with this issue.
I've got this kind of navigation:

```
  <nav class="navigation">
              <ul class="nav-items">
                <li class="nav-items__item"><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
                <li class="nav-items__item"><a href="about.html">Обо мне</a></li>
                <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_on-hover"><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_no-margin"><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav-sub-items">
                <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub"><a href="index.html">Саск-Политех</a></li>
                <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub"><a href="about.html">Школы</a></li>
                <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub"><a href="#">Курсы и кемпы </a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

The thing is that the **ul.nav-sub-items** is hidden by default. When hovering over **li.nav-items__item nav-items__item_on-hover** I wanna the **.nav-sub-items** show up. Just classic. But the thing is that, I wrote some jQuery, which won't work at all. Can someone, please, help me?

Here comes the jQ:

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav-items__item_on-hover').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.nav-sub-items').show('fast');
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.nav-sub-items').hide('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

**[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/rm9prsjn/5/)**

Put `ul` element inside `li` so if you have multi hidden `sub menu` it can show that too.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.nav-items__item_on-hover a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.nav-sub-items').show('fast');
  }, function(){
    $(this).next('.nav-sub-items').hide('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
   <ul class="nav-items">
  <li class="nav-items__item"><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items__item"><a href="about.html">Обо мне</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_on-hover">
   <a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <ul class="nav-sub-items" style="display:none">
     <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub">
       <a href="index.html">Саск-Политех</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub">
     <a href="about.html">Школы</a>
      </li>
     <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_sub">
     <a href="#">Курсы и кемпы </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-items__item nav-items__item_no-margin">
   <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>    
  </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the same list you want to show / hide, Simply show/hide it with the classname as shown below :

```
$(function(){
 $('.nav-items__item_on-hover').hover(function(){
    $('.nav-sub-items').show('fast');
    }, function(){
    $('.nav-sub-items').hide('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you man. But here comes one problem. As you can see, that block which is coming from display: none view, is not a child of the li, on the one I hover. So when I take the mouse away from that li element, the sub block fade away. Is there a way to keep it toggling while the mouse is it's area?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are classifying your li elements instead of the link itself. Move the classes over into the `<a>` tags, and then simply do this and it should work:

```
$('a.nav-items_item_on-hover').hover(function() {
    $('.nav-sub-items').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('.nav-sub-items').fadeOut();
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep4wmdme/1/)

To keep the toggled navigation block active, you can attach a `.on('mouseleave')` event to the entire container. When you move the mouse away from the container, the nav will then disappear again.

Example:

```
$('a.nav-items_item_on-hover').hover(function() {
    $('.nav-sub-items').fadeIn();
});

$('.navigation').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.nav-sub-items').fadeOut();
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep4wmdme/2/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you man. But here comes one problem. As you can see, that block which is coming from display: none view, is not a child of the li, on the one I hover. So when I take the mouse away from that li element, the sub block fade away. Is there a way to keep it toggling while the mouse is it's area?

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer. Take a look at the jsFiddle

Comment: Thank you very much bro!